# Change default decimal separator in pandas read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sybase

I'm creating a python script, that create csv files as result from sybase queries.

When pandas creates the file, all numeric values inside csv file ends with ".0" (for example, 2.0 instead of 2 )

I can cast to integer in query, but it affects query performance.

In order to solve that, I setted coerce_float parameter to false inside read_sql function.

However all columns are converted to string, and some columns must be floats, and the decimal separator is "." and I need "," as decimal separator.

My question is:
Is there some way to change default  decimal separator as a comma and keep coerce_float to False?

Obs: a simple string replace doesnt solve my problem, because the script will read several query files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, python uses "." to write floats so you cant have floats written with ",". If you want floats written with "," they must be strings. However, you can save floats with the decimal "," as you save the .csv, by passing the argument `decimal=','` to `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: It doesnt work because the coerce_float parameter is converting entire dataframe to string, and it continues to save with dot

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira thats why you should not use coerce_float, and modify the float decimal only when saving, else you are not able to use floats as floats, and you have to use them as strings, and I dont know your application but it doesnt seem convenient hehe

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira also, if you still want to continue using strings, I dont understand why you dont want to use string replace. You can use apply in the entire dataframe or map to do it by column.

Comment: It will run several queries, including string fields, and there ia a risk to improper substitutions